# How use libstdc++ instead libc++ (MacOS 12.0)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, libstdc++, libc++

I need to install **nodejs 8.17** for my work-project (MacOS 12.0).
I decided to use NVM (because I want to switch between npm versions), and I got following message:

> clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]

As far as I understand, I need to install or set preferences for libstdc++.
I tried to use `xcode-select --install`, but I got `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`.

Comment: You'll need to install libstdc++ yourself; Apple does not ship (or support) it on Mac OS.

Comment: @MarshallClow as far as I understood, Mac OS has libstdc++ for old versions (it was included into Xcode).

Comment: Yes, but certainly not for Mac OS 12.   Try Mac OS X 10.7 or so.  There is no libstdc++ dylib on "modern" Mac OS installations.

Comment: I don't have other macbook :D, I can't change mac OS

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

`libstdc++` is targeted and optimized for GCC/G++, not *AppleClang*.  There have been versions which have worked with *llvm-clang*, so it could perhaps, in theory, be made to work with *Apple*.  cf. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html